# error while running gradient vector flow

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i was trying gradient vector field for segmentation from [gvf](http://www.nitrc.org/frs/download.php/1962/gvf_v5.zip). Code is in examples-gvf_ex.m .I changed the code as

```
I=rgb2gray(I);
I=im2double(I)
```

Input image is

[image: input]

actual output is
[image: actual output]

i'm expecting somewhat like this(without that rectangular portion)
[image: expected output]

Comment: The original code using the provided example image runs fine, what did you change to use your image?

Comment: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." means that at that line of code you are trying to assign something (variable.matrix/function) to a variable which does not have the same size.

Comment: Now your question contains part of the updated code, but still the original question. That makes no sense.

Comment: updated with expected output and actual output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using is designed for greyscale images of type double. You are inputting a rgb-image of type uint8.

Use `rgb2gray` and `im2double` to convert.

Comment: still i'm a getting a rectangular gray image as output.how to change the parameters of snake?

Comment: To be honest, I have no Idea what you expect to happen. The example images are simple lines, not sure what you expect to happen.